# Could not create Makefile when installing ruby gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, makefile, rubygems, osx-mountain-lion

I'm running `OSX 10.8.2`, Xcode installed with command line tools.

I'm trying to bundle, and on some gems (I'll specify at the bottom) I am getting the following:

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
```

...

```
Could not create Makefile due to some reason
```

So far I get the error on the `gem 'pg'` and `gem 'binding_of_caller'`

I believe the error has something to do with the inability to create Makefile, but can't find anything helpful to solve the error. I've pasted the full error below:

I'm at a loss for what to do.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pqlib
--without-pqlib
--with-libpqlib
--without-libpqlib
--with-ms/libpqlib
--without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ericavirtue/.bundler/tmp/75812/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ericavirtue/.bundler/tmp/75812/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.14.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

EDIT: I'm using `rbenv` to manage ruby versions and it says I am running `1.9.3 -p385`The system ruby is an older version, but that shouldn't matter as far as I know.

I have `postgresql` installed via `homebrew`

EDIT 2:

I tried switching to `RVM` for ruby management, but get another make error:

```
Error running 'make -j2', please read ... ruby-1.9.3-p385/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The file make.log doesn't exist ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install postgres. From http://deveiate.org/code/pg/README_rdoc.html you need:

- Ruby 1.8.7-p249 or 1.9.3-p0.
- PostgreSQL 8.3.x (with headers, -dev packages, etc).

if you're using brew, just

```
brew install postgresql
```

As far as binding_of_caller, what version of ruby are you using?

Comment: rbenv says I'm using ruby version 1.9.3 p-385, which I'm using on my other machine no problem. I just did brew install postgresql and it  installed. I'm still getting the same error when trying to bundle with the pg gem in my gemfile. I also get the same error when I try to just install the gem with sudo gem install pg

Comment: I just type bundle or bundle install

Comment: Also, see the Edits to my question

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this problem by doing `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg` which got pg installed, but now I'm having different problems when I try to create the database, run the server, etc. I'll create another question for those problems.

Comment: ack, I was going to suggest that, but thought it wasn't your issue. Sorry