# Could not create Makefile for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, makefile, bundle, osx-mountain-lion

I can't install the pg gem when I run bundle, or when I try to install it separately. The error I get is: "could not create Makefile." I'm running Mountain Lion, have Xcode installed, and have command line tools installed. I also have Postregsql installed via homebrew.

I believe the error is because I can't create the makefile, which has surfaced as the error preventing me from doing other things.

The full error I get is below.

This error happens during the bundle. The other gems are installed fine, or are marked as using, then this error terminates the bundle while `installing pg (0.14.1) with native extensions`

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pqlib
--without-pqlib
--with-libpqlib
--without-libpqlib
--with-ms/libpqlib
--without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ericavirtue/.bundler/tmp/75812/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ericavirtue/.bundler/tmp/75812/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.14.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm really at a loss for what to do here. I've been working on this for two days.

EDIT:

So when trying to find the path to implement the solution Christian Rapp suggested I found this recommendation: `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg` which worked to install pg. Unfortunately I'm getting errors when I try to run `rails s`, `rake db:create:all`, or `rake db:migrate`. I'll create a separate question to trace those problems down ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not create Makefile when installing ruby gems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950787/could-not-create-makefile-when-installing-ruby-gems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not using homebrew on MacOS but where does it install libpq? MacPorts is using /opt and your configure script does not know anything about this. The error messages is quite informative just provide the path with something like

> gem install pg -- --with-libpqlib=/opt/...

May be you have to use another flag to provide the necessary Informations

Comment: Sorry, can you be a bit more explicit? so I run bundle --with-libpqlib=/opt/?

Comment: I edited my answer, but first you have to find out where homebrew puts the packages you install with it. That is the path you have to provide

Answer (score 2):

The error is this:

> Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)

You'll need to install PostreSQL (I recommend using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), but there are probably other downloads available) and try to install the gem again.

Comment: I already installed postregsql with homebrew and got the same error. I'm able to see homebrew is installed, but can't start it because I can't create a database because the gem isn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

**"Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)"**

This is the reason your makefile can't be created. Your Postgres libraries, specifically libpq can't be found on your path. I see you installed with Homebrew. I don't use homebrew so I don't know if it sets the path for you.

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix this? I'm pretty new to command line, so I'm not sure how to make it so libpq can be found on my path?